# How to write css selector for this <span _ngcontent-eyw-6="">A</span>

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I need to locate this span element through css selector. Can anyone help me?

```
<h2 class="label-top" _ngcontent-eyw-7="">
<span _ngcontent-eyw-6="">A</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Anything wrong with .label-top span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xpath with `h2`:

```
//h2[contains(@class, 'label-top')]//span[contains(text(), 'A')]
```

Or without `h2`

```
//span[contains(text(), 'A')]
```

Or you can do it with CSS but without containing text

```
"h2.label-top span"
```

Checkout this [XPath Cheat sheet](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf)